# passing parameter to function called in ng-show

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I want to call the function with parameter in ng-show. 
I caught error Error: [$parse:syntax] Syntax Error: Token ']' not a primary expression at column 8 of the expression [cheked[]] starting at []].I want to pass the parameter `{{data.id}}`

```
<div class="box box-primary" ng-show="cheked[{{data.id}}]">
<div class="box-body showmycomments" ng-show="cheked[{{data.id}}] "">
```

If I call the function as `ng-show="cheked({{data.id}})"` |I caught the error as TypeError: v2.cheked is not a function

Answer (score 3):

You dont need interpolate expressions (`{{}}`) in your `ngShow`:

```
ng-show="cheked(data.id)"
```

Comment: In my js I called as '$scope.cheked=cheked(id);' to avoid TypeError: v2.cheked is not a function

Comment: So where you actually had your checked function defined ??